# why is raspberry pi no wireless interfaces found. no wireless extension

Tags: raspbian, wireless, internet

no wireless interfaces found. If I connect through ethernet cable, it works.
any idea how to solve it?[image]

Comment: `no wireless interfaces found` ... what do you  think that `wlan0` is?

Comment: the image is the output when connected through Ethernet cable. Although it is showing something here, it says 'no wireless interfaces found' on the rasbian interface at the top right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the command is not visible, your screenshot seems to show the output of `iwconfig`.

It tells you all the relevant details about the wireless interface `wlan0`, e.g. that it is in managed mode, but not connected to an access point.
With respect to the other interfaces `lo` the loopback interface, `eth0` your ethernet interface, etc. it tells you that those are **no** wireless interfaces.

If you want to connect your wireless interface `wlan0` to an access point, you should be able to do it without problems following for example the official tutorials for a [desktop environment](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/desktop.md) or [command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).

Comment: this problem occured when I tried to set up headless. After I installed Noobs and connect with HDMI cable, the issue is gone.